# Error in stripe payment using node js

Tags: ios, payment-gateway, payment, stripe-payments

i am using stripe payment in our application. Its working fine in development but gives error on live app with US card.Testing taking place in India using US card.
Below is error log in node js. 
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you try to take an `application_fee` but you don't provide the `access_token` from your connected user as the second parameter to the [Create Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) API.

To take an `application_fee` you need to be using [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) which means you are creating a Charge on behalf of a connected user. To do this, you need to follow those steps:

- On the front-end you need to use the `publishable_key` you got from the connected user when going through the Connect flow. You should *not* use your API key.
- Once you get a card token you send it to your server where you will create a charge. There, you should *not* set your API key but you should pass the `access_token` of the connected user as a second parameter to the Create Charge API. You can see some example code in the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collecting-fees) showing how to collect fees.